# Finding the complex fourier series of the function $x^2\sin(x)$ in the interval $[{-\pi}, \pi]$?

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis, summation, fourier-series

This forms part of a project I am doing and I wish to see how well complex fourier series approximates a smooth curve such as this one. After tedious integration by parts, I have attained an answer which has imaginary numbers in, although I have been advised that $C_{n}$ must be real.

Ignoring that, when trying to plot what I have derived to see how well it approximates the original function, the graph is not much like the original function. I have checked my work repeatedly but I must have made an error.

The answer I have attained is: $\sum_{n=-N}^{N} \Bigg(\dfrac{i(-1)^n}{(n-1)^2} - \dfrac{i(-1)^n}{(n+1)^2} \Bigg) e^{inx}$

If this answer is correct, is the fact that the fourier series is trying to approximate a smooth function mean it's hard to be correct? The discontinuous functions I have approximated have worked brilliantly with a suitably large n.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "complex fourier series"? What is the definition you are using?

Answer (score 3):

The coefficient I get is

$$\frac{4 i (-1)^n n}{(n^2-1)^2},$$ which is not the same as yours.

For $n = 1,$ mathematica gives
$$-\frac{1}{6} i \pi  \left(2 \pi ^2-3\right)$$

and for $n=-1,$
$$\frac{1}{6} i \pi  \left(2 \pi ^2-3\right)$$

Comment: That was the first answer I got! However, when I tried to plot this, it didn't get very close to the original function. Did you compute this using maple or similar software?

Comment: Mathematica, yes.

Comment: This is your $C_{n}$ for n = 2 or greater, right? To get $C_{1}$, am I correct in thinking I need to integrate again taking n = 1?

Comment: Why should $n=1$ be different?

Comment: I am not 100% sure in my thinking, but in the summation, you can't have n = 1 as you will have 0 as the denominator. Unless you can split up the summation from - N to 2, 2 to N?

Comment: $n=\pm1$ will be different, because what you guys have is a division by zero problem.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Ah, I did not look.Obviously the defining integral should be finite, so mathematica is being silly.

Comment: Because I have to do it by hand for my project, I have $\dfrac{1}{4\pi i} \Bigg( \dfrac{{-4\pi}(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)^2} + \dfrac{4\pi(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2} \Bigg)$. This does simplify to the answer you got, right?

Comment: @Adam See my answer.  It is your answer, but you need corrections for the case $n = \pm 1$.

Comment: @Adam Also, notice $(-1)^{n+1} = (-1)^{n-1} = - (-1)^n$.

Comment: And for your answers for $n = -1, 1$, did you include the $\dfrac{1}{2\pi}$ at the front? I believe I would have the same otherwise. Thanks very much you two with the help.

Comment: No, I forgot that part, good catch...

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith The answer I mentioned a few comments above seems to come out as negative your answer. I know you said my answer is correct but I think when simplifying my answer, it comes out as negative?

Comment: It is very easy to be off by a minus sign when doing these calculations.  I must admit that I usually check them by graphing on a computer.

Comment: @IgorRivin I have never used Mathematica before but have downloaded a trial version. How would I plot this complex fourier series?

Comment: Mathematica gets $c_1 = -\frac{1}{12} i \left(2 \pi ^2-3\right)$ and $c_{-1} = \frac{1}{12} i \left(2 \pi ^2-3\right)$.

Answer (score 3):

The Fourier series for $x^2$ on $(-\pi,\pi)$ is
$$ \frac{\pi^2}3 + 4 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} \cos nx \\
= \frac{\pi^2}3 + 2 \sum_{n=-\infty\atop n\ne 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} e^{inx} $$
So the Fourier series for $e^{ix} x^2$ is
$$ \frac{\pi^2}3e^{ix} + 2 \sum_{n=-\infty\atop n\ne 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n-1)^2} e^{inx} $$
So the Fourier series for $\sin(x) x^2 = \frac1{2i} (e^{ix}-e^{-ix}) x^2$ is
$$ \frac{\pi^2}3 \sin(x) + i\sum_{n=-\infty\atop n\ne 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n-1)^2} e^{inx} - i\sum_{n=-\infty\atop n\ne -1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n+1)^2} e^{inx} $$
So if $n \ne \pm 1$, then the Fourier coefficient of $e^{inx}$ is
$$ i(-1)^n \left(\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}- \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right) $$
and this is the same as Igor Riven's answer.  The cases $n=\pm1$ need to be calculated separately, but will be easy (basically the above with the divisions by zero replacing the offending term by what comes from the $\frac{\pi^2}3 \sin(x)$ term).

Comment: Do you know why the plot of the complex fourier series for this function is quite different to the original function? Is it because it's a smooth curve?

Comment: I tried plotting the $N=5$ complex Fourier series against the original function, and I got a very good fit.  I think you made some small error somewhere in your code.

Comment: Hmm. I am only using wolfram alpha! Will try in Maple once I am back at university. One last question, why does Cn have to be real? Thanks!

Comment: $c_n$ doesn't have to be real.  But it does have to satisfy $c_{-n} = \bar c_n$.

Comment: I tried to use Wolfram alpha, but it seems to truncate the input if the input line is too long.  The plots that worked for me were done using Mathematica.

Comment: @Adam There are other online graphing tools: try [fooplot](http://fooplot.com). The input window is tiny, but you can paste long formulas typed elsewhere, and it won't complain or truncate them.

Comment: @PostNoBills I had a quick try, but it doesn't seem to like the imaginary numbers, summations or n variable?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith You said you tried N = 5 and you got a very good fit in Mathematica... I have plotted in Mathematica too now and it's not a particularly good fit either (same as Wolfram Alpha for me). I don't know whether I am expecting too much. How did you plot it? I split up the summation like you can with complex fourier series so I was just plotting from 2 to 10, avoiding negatives.

Comment: c1[n_] := 1/2/Pi Integrate[x^2 Sin[x] Exp[-I n x], {x, -Pi, Pi}];
c2[n_] = Simplify[c1[n], Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers]];
c[n_] := If[n == 1, c1[1], If[n == -1, c1[-1], c2[n]]];
f5[x_] = Sum[c[k] Exp[I k x], {k, -5, 5}];
Plot[{f5[x], x^2 Sin[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}]

Comment: The reason might be that it seems Igor got the values for $c_1$ and $c_{-1}$ off by a factor of two.  When I executed the code in my previous comment, it was quite difficult to visually see a difference between the two curves.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, he forgot the $1/2\pi$. However, these cancel out anyway I believe, so you are just left with the fourier coefficient. When trying to plot the answer directly (instead of integrating), the plot isn't right.

Comment: No, they don't cancel out.  That is why your plot isn't working.

Comment: I guessed that may be the problem, but they still appear to cancel out from my computations. One is just negative lots of the other? Am I mistaken that you simply add these coefficients to the outside of the summation like you do with $C_{0}$ (which is 0 here anyway)?

Comment: One is multiplied by $e^{ix}$, the other by $e^{-ix}$.  So after they are added in, they don't cancel.

Comment: Oh! I forgot to add the $e^{inx}$ after. Thank you very much for your help.